# Normalize/Standardize a numpy recarray

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, normalize, recarray

I wonder what the best way of normalizing/standardizing a numpy `recarray` is.
To make it clear, I'm not talking about a mathematical matrix, but a record array that also has e.g. textual columns (such as labels).

```
a = np.genfromtxt("iris.csv", delimiter=",", dtype=None)
print a.shape
> (150,)
```

As you can see, I cannot e.g. process `a[:,:-1]` as the shape is one-dimensional.

The best I found is to iterate over all columns:

```
for nam in a.dtype.names[:-1]:
    col = a[nam]
    a[nam] = (col - col.min()) / (col.max() - col.min())
```

Any more elegant way of doing this? Is there some method such as "normalize" or "standardize" somewhere?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do it, but some are cleaner than others.

Usually, in numpy, you keep the string data in a separate array.

(Things are a bit more low-level than, say, R's data frame. You typically just wrap things up in a class for the association, but keep different data types separate.)

Honestly, numpy isn't optimized for handling "flexible" datatypes such as this (though it can certainly do it).  Things like [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/index.html) provide a better interface for "spreadsheet-like" data (and pandas is just a layer on top of numpy).

However, structured arrays (which is what you have here) will allow you to slice them column-wise when you pass in a list of field names.  (e.g. `data[['col1', 'col2', 'col3']]`)

At any rate, one way is to do something like this:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.recfromcsv('iris.csv')

# In this case, it's just all but the last, but we could be more general
# This must be a list and not a tuple, though.
float_fields = list(data.dtype.names[:-1])

float_dat = data[float_fields]

# Now we just need to view it as a "regular" 2D array...
float_dat = float_dat.view(np.float).reshape((data.size, -1))

# And we can normalize columns as usual.
normalized = (float_dat - float_dat.min(axis=0)) / float_dat.ptp(axis=0)
```

However, this is far from ideal. If you want to do the operation in-place (as you currently are) the easiest solution is what you already have: Just iterate over the field names.

Incidentally, using `pandas`, you'd do something like this:

```
import pandas
data = pandas.read_csv('iris.csv', header=None)

float_dat = data[data.columns[:-1]]
dmin, dmax = float_dat.min(axis=0), float_dat.max(axis=0)

data[data.columns[:-1]] = (float_dat - dmin) / (dmax - dmin)
```

Comment: +1 Thank you. This is a very informative and insightful answer. Splitting the dataset into numerical and non-numerical columns is probably the way to go. This makes many other operations well-defined and is in fact what I was trying to do. I wasn't aware of the option of using `data[list]` to select multiple columns.

Answer (score 1):

What version of NumPy are you using? With version 1.5.1, I don't get this behavior. I made a short text file as an example, saved as `test.txt`:

```
last,first,country,state,zip
tyson,mike,USA,Nevada,89146
brady,tom,USA,Massachusetts,02035
```

When I then execute the following code, this is what I get:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.genfromtxt("/home/ely/Desktop/Python/test.txt",delimiter=',',dtype=None)
>>> print a.shape
(3,5)
>>> print a
[['last' 'first' 'country' 'state' 'zip']
 ['tyson' 'mike' 'USA' 'Nevada' '89146']
 ['brady' 'tom' 'USA' 'Massachusetts' '02035']]
>>> print a[0,:-1]
['last' 'first' 'country' 'state']
>>> print a.dtype.names
None
```

I'm just wondering what's different about your data.

Comment: Note: this was meant as a comment, not an answer... just needed more room to put in the example above.

Comment: What's different is that you're getting a string array, not a structured array.  Have a look at the dtype of `a` in your example.

Comment: Sure, but what causes the incoming array to be 'structured'? If it's just a csv file, won't `genfromtxt()` always produce a string array?

Comment: Nope.  In your case, it's only creating a string array because the first row (the column names) are all strings.  If you had numbers in any column in the first row, you'd get a structured array.  In your case, if you specify `names=True`, the column names will be read from the first row, and you'll get a structured array.  (See [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html) for what I mean by "structured", by the way)

Comment: @JoeKington probably got the difference. I have four purely numerical columns that I want to standardize, and one that has the labels.