# Has the DataFrame object from pandas superceded the other alternatives for heterogeneous data types?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, pandas

Before, there was [larry](https://github.com/kwgoodman/la) and [structured/record arrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html) in NumPy, but I wonder if they are used any more with any frequency given the rapid development of the `pandas` package. Coming from R, I would always get stuck having to unpack the record arrays to modify values from multiple columns and reassign them back into the structure but I'm so glad that `pandas` now allows this for its data frames. I wonder if there are any uses for which record arrays are still superior (does it have some useful methods that `pandas` does not have)?

Comment: Wow, I totally forgot I asked a similar question earlier. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12052067/if-i-use-python-pandas-is-there-any-need-for-structured-arrays. I have been an infrequent programmer these days.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a good explanation and simple comparison between pandas and numpy record arrays - [Normalize/Standardize a numpy recarray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9775765/normalize-standardize-a-numpy-recarray/9776155#9776155)