# Normalize numpy array columns in python

Tags: python, numpy, normalize

I have a numpy array where each cell of a specific row represents a value for a feature. I store all of them in an 100*4 matrix.

```
A     B   C
1000  10  0.5
765   5   0.35
800   7   0.09
```

Any idea how I can normalize rows of this numpy.array where each value is between 0 and 1?

My desired output is:

```
A     B    C
1     1    1
0.765 0.5  0.7
0.8   0.7  0.18(which is 0.09/0.5)
```

Comment: Just to be clear: is it a NumPy array or a Pandas DataFrame?

Comment: When programming it's important to be specific: a `set` is a particular object in Python, and you can't have a set of numpy arrays.  Python doesn't have a matrix, but numpy does, and that `matrix` type isn't the same as a numpy `array/ndarray` (which is itself different from Python's `array` type, which is not the same as a `list`).  And none of these are pandas `DataFrame`s..

Comment: I do not think this is a complete normalization. I would look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9775765/normalize-standardize-a-numpy-recarray for a better definition of normalization.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

If I understand correctly, what you want to do is divide by the maximum value in each column. You can do this easily using [broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html).

Starting with your example array:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[1000,  10,   0.5],
              [ 765,   5,  0.35],
              [ 800,   7,  0.09]])

x_normed = x / x.max(axis=0)

print(x_normed)
# [[ 1.     1.     1.   ]
#  [ 0.765  0.5    0.7  ]
#  [ 0.8    0.7    0.18 ]]
```

`x.max(0)` takes the maximum over the 0th dimension (i.e. rows). This gives you a vector of size `(ncols,)` containing the maximum value in each column. You can then divide `x` by this vector in order to normalize your values such that the maximum value in each column will be scaled to 1.

---

If `x` contains negative values you would need to subtract the minimum first:

```
x_normed = (x - x.min(0)) / x.ptp(0)
```

Here, `x.ptp(0)` returns the "peak-to-peak" (i.e. the range, max - min) along axis 0. This normalization also guarantees that the minimum value in each column will be 0.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer, I always have issues dealing with "axis" !

Comment: For reductions (i.e. `.max()`, `.min()`, `.sum()`, `.mean()` etc.), you just need to remember that `axis` specifies the dimension that you want to "collapse" during the reduction. If you want the maximum for each column, then you need to collapse the the row dimension.

Comment: @rawbeans See my update. The reason I divided by the maximum is because that's what the OP showed in their example.

Comment: @ali_m, Would you please explain why you are saying "If x contains negative values"? If the minimum of the array is 100 and the maximum is 103, I think you should definitely use your second formula, otherwise your result will not have a 0 offset.

Comment: @lman Simply because that's exactly what the OP showed in their example. *"Between 0 and 1"* is ambiguous - it doesn't necessarily imply that the minimum value must be zero, only that all of the values must be >= 0 and <= 1.

Comment: Note that this broadcast notation won't work if collapsing any axis other than 0; if you want to normalize the rows, you'll need to be more explicit in the division step, or it will normalize the columns by the sums of the rows!

Comment: @GalacticKetchup You can easily extend this to reductions over arbitrary axes by passing `keepdims=True` to the reduction ufunc. This arg prevents the reduction axis from getting "squeezed out" so that broadcasting will still work correctly, e.g. `x / x.max(axis=1, keepdims=True)`.

Answer (score 31):

You can use sklearn.preprocessing:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize
data = np.array([
    [1000, 10, 0.5],
    [765, 5, 0.35],
    [800, 7, 0.09], ])
data = normalize(data, axis=0, norm='max')
print(data)
>>[[ 1.     1.     1.   ]
[ 0.765  0.5    0.7  ]
[ 0.8    0.7    0.18 ]]
```

Comment: Any way to scale the column values between ``1`` and ``2`? Using MinMaxScaler?