# Manhattan distance problem in python without using scikit learn module?

Tags: python, predictive

I need to predict the level of a certain index for a country (Scale of 1-100) which is the target feature  based on 5 macro-economic and social features/indicators ( Life expectancy , infant mortality , % of GDP spent on military etc  )

I need to use 3-nearest neighbor prediction model &  weighted k-nn

I also need to predict after range normalization.

Im looking for some ideas on how I could achieve this in python

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to avoid using scikit for this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also kindly asking: Is this for an assignment of somekind?

Comment: Also, do you know how the weighted knn and the manhattan distance work. And what kind of normalization do you want? Please add more details to the question

Comment: yes the requirement is specific. Im getting started in python so really dont have any direction at the moment . any suggestions would be welcome

Comment: yes i know how they work. standard or min-max normalization should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should start by doing this **with** scikit-learn and get is to work.

Then you should work on a function for the manhattan distance, so just:

```py
def dist_manhattan(point1, point2):
    ...
```

If you got this you need to implement your normalization function:

```py
def normalize(dataset):
    ...
```

and then you can implement your weighted knn, like a function

```py
def w_knn(dataset):
    ...
```

and if you have general struggel with python, I would suggest reading some books about it or watching/reading tutorials.

Comment: so i was able to work with lists to find the CPI for russia using manhattan distance  without normalization  
i now need to normalize the data before i need to find the Manhattan distance between the parameters for the countries against Russia
so the thing is i need to normalize column wise (the parameters) and then i need to find the manhattan distance row wise
any idea on how this could be achieved becuase it some point I think I will have to flip the data frame or if working with lists how can i get the first values from the 5 columns (lists) into 16 lists with 5 values each  ?

Comment: @axel_p take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29661574/6560579)